# when i have 2 Swipeable react butttons. while im slide button 1 & button 2 is moving

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when i slide slider1 is moving wrong slider
[slider image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0ChH.png)

u can test at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-lake-4dryy?file=/src/App.js)

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-lake-4dryy?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please include relevant code in the question itself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a single `container` and `slider` ref.

Those need to tied to the component, not the component's module. In other words, both component instances are referring to the same refs.

E.g., you could create them in a constructor:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.slider = React.createRef();
  this.container = React.createRef();
}
```

The update all references to them in the component, e.g., `this.container`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-worker-7ucvr?file=/src/ReactSwipeButton.js